# Google Chart Color

Tags: colors, charts

I'm learning Google Chart API, and found the following code that I can use, but how to specify my own colors, I searched on Google site, it says use chco, but in this situation, how to use "chco:FFC6A5|FFFF42|DEF3BD|00A5C6" here, where do I specify that ?

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
        data.addRows(4);
        data.setValue(0, 0, '2004');
        data.setValue(0, 1, 1000);
        data.setValue(0, 2, 400);
        data.setValue(1, 0, '2005');
        data.setValue(1, 1, 1170);
        data.setValue(1, 2, 460);
        data.setValue(2, 0, '2006');
        data.setValue(2, 1, 660);
        data.setValue(2, 2, 1120);
        data.setValue(3, 0, '2007');
        data.setValue(3, 1, 1030);
        data.setValue(3, 2, 540);

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, title: 'Company Performance',
                          hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
                         });
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, I got it, it's like this :

```
chart.draw(data_Of_Day, { colors:['#A2C180','#3D7930','#FFC6A5','#FFFF42','#DEF3BD','#00A5C6','#DEBDDE','#000000'], width:1410, height:610, ....
```