# Color Google Column Bar depending by its value

Tags: colors, google-visualization

I need to change bar color in depending by its value.

There is a nice solution [TableFormatter for tables](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table.html) but it does not working for column chart that I am using.

I saw these topics:

- [Google Chart, different color for each bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375248/google-chart-diferent-color-for-each-bar),
- [Google Chart Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445072/google-chart-color)

Also I saw a solution using jQuery, to change attribute inside iframe, but I want to find better solution.

My code is at http://jsfiddle.net/Xxn42/4/ or here:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart', 'table']});  

var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Department');
data.addColumn('number', 'Revenues');
data.addRows(6);
data.setCell(0, 0, 'Shoes');
data.setCell(0, 1, 10700);
data.setCell(1, 0, 'Sports');
data.setCell(1, 1, -15400);
data.setCell(2, 0, 'Toys');
data.setCell(2, 1, 12500);
data.setCell(3, 0, 'Electronics');
data.setCell(3, 1, -2100);
data.setCell(4, 0, 'Food');
data.setCell(4, 1, 22600);
data.setCell(5, 0, 'Art');
data.setCell(5, 1, 1100);

// Create and draw the visualization.
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(
  document.getElementById('visualization'));
var table = new google.visualization.Table(
  document.getElementById('table'));   

var formatter = new google.visualization.TableColorFormat();
formatter.addRange(-20000, 0, 'white', 'orange');
formatter.addRange(20000, null, 'red', '#33ff33');
formatter.format(data, 1); // Apply formatter to second column

chart.draw(data, {legend: 'none'});  
table.draw(data, {allowHtml:true, showRowNumber: true});
```