# Multiple Colors in a Series with Google Charts Api

Tags: api, charts

I am new to google charts and am having a little trouble specifying options.

I have a bar chart with one series that I want each bar to be a different color on.  Here's what I tried:

```
var data = response.getDataTable();
    var options = { width: 350, height: 240, title: "Test", is3D: true };
    options.colors = [["#FF00FF","#0000FF"]];

    var title = data.getTableProperty("title");
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('MultipleSeriesPriorityChart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

This ends up saying "#FF00FF","#0000FF" is an invalid color.

After doing some searching I found that when doing a google chart via a url, you can get this behavior by simply including this parameter:

chco=FF0000|00FF00|0000FF

What I'm wondering is, is there any way I can mimic this behavior using google.visualization.BarChart.  Or, is there a way I can just specify the chco option?

Thanks

Comment: Please view the solution in:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445072/google-chart-color

Answer (score 1):

Use options.colors = **["#FF00FF","#0000FF"]**; instead of

> options.colors = [["#FF00FF","#0000FF"]];

Comment: If you use it you get the error: #7b1315,#6b999f is not a valid color string